# Can't center this div inside a div

Tags: css, alignment, center

Been looking for other answers but non of them worked.

I want to center the div inside each row both horizontally and vertically, nothing seems to be working.

```html
<div class="border" style="width:100%; height:500px; min-height:500px; position:relative;">
    <div class="border" style="display:inline-block; width:33%; height:500px; position:relative;">
        <div class="border" style="width:90%; height:90%; position:absolute; display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="border" style="display:inline-block; width:33%; height:500px;"/>
    <div class="border" style="display:inline-block; width:33%; height:500px;"/>
</div>
```

I tried with `top` and `left:50%` and `transform`, `margin: 0 auto;` and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `position:absolute; display:inline-block;` as well as `display:inline-block;` in the parent, and it centered the green div inside the blue one (I added colored borders so that the divs become visible):

```html
<div class="border" style="border: 1px solid red; width:100%; height:500px; min-height:500px; position:relative;">
    <div class="border" style="border: 3px solid blue; width:33%; height:500px; position:relative;">
        <div class="border" style="border: 3px solid green; width:90%; height:90%; margin: 0 auto;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="border" style="border: 1px solid orange; display:inline-block; width:33%; height:500px;"/>
    <div class="border" style="border: 1px solid black; display:inline-block; width:33%; height:500px;"/>
</div>
```

So `margin: 0 auto` is the way to go whatever you actually want to center - which is unclear.